# How to create a relationship with Neo4j Graphql?

Tags: neo4j, graphql, relationship

Hi I'm in a migration from neo4j-graphql-js.

Here was my setup, this is the abridged/relevant parts of the definition:

```
type Playlist {
    id: ID!,
    name: String!,
    things: [Thing] @relationship(type: "HAS_THING", direction: OUT),
}
```

```
mutation ADD_THING_TO_PLAYLIST($playlistId: ID!, $thingId: ID!){
  AddPlaylistThings(from: { id: $playlistId }, to: {id: $thingId}){
    to{
      id
    }
  }
}
```

And this is what I have now. It returns the proper playlist but things remains empty. `relationshipsCreated` returns 0.

```
mutation ADD_THING_TO_PLAYLIST($playlistId: ID!, $thingId: ID!){
  updatePlaylists(
    where: { id: $playlistId },
    connect: { things: { where: { node: { id:$thingId } }}}
  ){
    playlists {
      id
      things {
         id
       }
    }
    info {
      relationshipsCreated
    }
  }
}
```

Any idea what may be going wrong and how I should be setting up this `connect`? It appears correct based on the [documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/graphql-manual/current/guides/migration-guide/mutations/#_connecting) and lack of errors being spit out at me.

Comment: Upgrading the database itself worked. Have mentioned to the team it should be in the docs.